# In what scenario 'this' pointer is passed to the class methods?

Tags: c++, this, class-method

I was doing some reading on the 'this' pointer, and I think I understand it more than I originally did, but I still need some clarification. So, by my understanding, if you have

```
class Simple
{
private:
    int m_nID;

public:
    Simple(int nID)
    {
        SetID(nID);
    }

    void SetID(int nID) { m_nID = nID; }
    int GetID() { return m_nID; }
};
```

The SetID(int nID) function actually is semantically converted into:

```
void SetID(Simple* const this, int nID) { this->m_nID = nID; }
```

It makes sense that, there is a `this` pointer for all member functions of a class, for the most part. But what happens if you have a member function that takes no arguments? Is there a 'this' pointer? If so, does it point to the return type instead of the argument type?

Comment: Actually, I believe I have proven my own stupidity just now...

Comment: Why so, question seems to be OK?

Comment: After looking at the code I realize the hidden argument C++ adds is a pointer to the instance of the class and not the argument. Nevertheless, I guess my question about whether or not there is a 'this' pointer for member functions without arguments still stands.

Comment: @WorthyToast trying to understand exactly how things work is a good attitude in a complex domain like programming. C++ has a steep learning curve and it is perfectly normal to get confused sometimes about things that will seem obvious once you have understood them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what happens if you have a member function that takes no
>   arguments? Is there a 'this' pointer? If so, does it point to the
>   return type instead of the argument type?

Even your method do not have any argument, it still have one hidden parameter, that is `this` pointer.

Comment: In cases of no arguments, is there any real purpose of the hidden argument? In other words, are there any examples off the top of your head that you can think of where `*this` would be used without any other arguments?

Comment: @UnworthyToast In your getter (which has no arguments), simply replace the line you have with `return this->m_nID;` for a trivial example

Comment: @UnworthyToast There is confusion. `this` pointer is used to access member of object and not method. Even you do not have any parameter in function, you can still access all the member of object, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

All class methods that aren't static get a this pointer.

[This article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/) gives some ideas about when you might want to use the this pointer.

The presence of the this pointer in C++ has to do with the calling convention. It means there are differences on how space on the stack and in cpu registers is reserved for parameters to functions.

Non static methods in C++ normally use the [thiscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall) convention as opposed to other conventions (varying between compilers and architectures).