# Is "this" a default parameter in a class method?

Tags: c++, this

I've read somewhere that the "this" keyword is a default parameter (I suppose it's invisible or something) in any method of a class.
Is this true?

Comment: Simple answer : yes. For code generation, it is very similar to having an extra parameter `ClassName * const this`. However, usage is different as you don't have to write `this->` to access members while inside a member function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492736/what-is-the-this-pointer

Comment: As a neat bit of trivia, the ability to add an _explicit_ object parameter to member functions is currently part of a proposal for C++23. See [P0847R7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html).

Comment: And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667653/does-every-c-member-function-take-this-as-an-input-implicitly

Comment: `this` is often implemented as a hidden parameter, but technically how `this` gets into the method doesn't matter. You could teleport it in with Elf magic and still have a compliant implementation.

Comment: @Brian I am not sure that level of complexity is needed to achieve the goal. Why not allow a method to be defined like: `auto & foo () auto { ... }`. Then the method is `const` or not, returns a `const` reference or not. `foo` has to call other `auto` or `const` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"default parameter" is the wrong term. `this` can be thought of as an implicit paramter passed to member functions. If there were no member functions then you could emulate them with free functions like this:

```
struct Foo {
    int x = 0;
};

void set_x(Foo* THIS, int x) {
    THIS->x = x;
}
```

However, member functions do exists and the above can be written as:

```
struct Foo {
    int x = 0;
    void set_x(int x) {
       this->x = x;
    }
};
```

`this` is not passed to `Foo::set_x` explicitly. Nevertheless, inside the method you can use it to refer to the current object. It can be said to be an implicit parameter to the member function.

However, thats not the whole story. In member functions you actually do not need `this` to refer to members of the class. Instead of `this->x` just `x` would work as well and in contrast to other languages it is common style to ommit the `this->` unless necessary. For more details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this.

Note that it is not an implicit parameter to **all** methods of a class. You cannot refer to the current object via `this` in a static member function, because there is no "current object" in a static member function.

Also compare to python where `self` is explicitly passed:

```
 class Foo:
     def __init__(self):
          self.x = 0
     def set_x(self,x):
          self.x = x
```

Comment: Indeed the name given the `this` parameter in the standard is the _implicit object parameter_. From 16.3.1/2: _"a member function is considered to have an extra parameter, called the implicit object parameter, which
represents the object for which the member function has been called"_

Answer (score 3):

You can think of it that way; i.e. when you make a method call

```
myObject.Foo(1, 2, 3);
```

and the method `Foo(int a, int b, int c)` executes, the code within the method has access to parameters `a`, `b`, and `c`, and also access to the pointer `this`:

```
void MyObjectClass :: Foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
   printf("a=%i b=%i c=%i this=%p\n", a, b, c, this);
}
```

... `this` isn't explicitly listed in the arguments list but it's passed as part of the method-call (since without it, `Foo` wouldn't have access to any of its own member-variables, which would be a problem for most methods)

Comment: *member variables* is the term, not local variables.

Comment: Yes, you're right -- I'll fix that.